# Hyperledger Block Chain Sample build error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

I am trying to setup an IBM Block Chain setup in my local environment.

I am referring to the below manual for setup : 
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html

When following these steps:

- 1) Setup the environment

  - Install GoLang
  - SETUP GOROOT & GOPATH
- 2) SETUP GITHUB

Under GITHUB setup, at point 6, When I try to run the command `go build ./`

It should give No errors/text. But it is giving an exception. Please have a look at below screenshot for an exact exception.

[Exception-screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E84Z.jpg)

Can anyone help me, how can I solve this error, Ideally build should be successful.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty obvious.
Replace 
`stub *shim.ChaincodeStub` with `stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface` everywhere in your `chaincode_start.go` file.

Furthermore, read the following issue on github as it will really help,
https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/ibm-blockchain-issues/issues/29